# Github desktop - branch dependency (update automatically?)

Tags: github, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging, github-desktop

I am new to Github and Github Desktop.

I have a branch "development", and another branch created "feature" based on "development".

Once another person pushes the updated code in the "development" branch - if I am at the "development" branch, fetch origin then pull, of course I will have the updated code locally. But what if I am in the "feature" branch? If I fetch origin and pull (assume there is no merge conflict), will the updated code in the "development" branch replace my code in the "feature" branch?

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 2):

In git:
If you pull from feature's origin, you will not receive the new changes.
If you pull from development's origin, you will receive the new changes.

In Github Desktop:
In order to update from development's origin go into Branch -> Update from development or press CTRL+SHIFT+U

Comment: Just to clarify: AFAIK, @ GitHub Desktop pressing, CTRL+SHIFT+U will update from your local development branch (not the remote), so first you'll have to pull on your local development branch, to ensure that it is up to date. Only after that you should press CTRL+SHIFT+U.